# Unable to grant all privileges to new user on Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-rds

I'm creating a new user in a Postgres database (AWS RDS) and trying to grant all privileges on all tables in public schema of an existing database to that user. It is failing with below error. I even tried after logging in as the rds_superuser (postgres) and got the same error.

psql (13.3, server 10.15)

```
test_db=> \dt
              List of relations
 Schema |     Name     | Type  |    Owner     
--------+--------------+-------+--------------
 public | table1       | table | test_user
 public | table2       | table | test_user
 public | table3       | table | test_user
(3 rows)

test_db=> CREATE ROLE new_user WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'by1ne8Cs0Z2' VALID UNTIL '2021-05-29';
CREATE ROLE

test_db=> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO new_user;
```

> ERROR:  permission denied for relation table1

Can someone help me out here?

EDIT: Found a workaround but not sure if this is the best approach. Logged in as the postgres user, ran the below query and then logged back in as the new_user and was able to run select queries on the tables.

```
test_db=> \du new_user
                                 List of roles
    Role name    |                 Attributes                  |   Member of    
-----------------+---------------------------------------------+----------------
 new_user        | Password valid until 2021-05-29 00:00:00+00 | {}

test_db=> GRANT test_user to new_user;

test_db=> \du new_user
                                 List of roles
    Role name    |                 Attributes                  |   Member of    
-----------------+---------------------------------------------+----------------
 new_user        | Password valid until 2021-05-29 00:00:00+00 | {test_user}
```

EDIT2: Please find the output below.

```
test_db=> \dp table1 
                               Access privileges
 Schema |    Name    | Type  | Access privileges | Column privileges | Policies 
--------+------------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+----------
 public | table1     | table |                   |                   | 
(1 row)
```

Comment: Please show `\dp table1`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe added the output to the question since the formatting was off in the comments.

Comment: That proves that you didn't grant the privileges. Perhaps you did it in a transaction that got rolled back?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe yes, I get the permission denied error when I try to grant all privileges. Any idea why it’s not going through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to issue the `GRANT` statements as user `test_user`.

Only the owner can grant privileges on an object (or a user who has been granted the privilege `WITH GRANT OPTION`).

Comment: Doesn’t the postgres user have that privilege considering it’s the superuser? The thing is we’re trying some dynamic rotation of credentials using vault and we can’t really login as the owner each time and create temporary roles.

Comment: Obviously `postgres` is *not* a superuser. Remember that you are *not* using PostgreSQL, but some modified version.

Comment: But when I run \du, postgres user says it is a member of rds_superuser

Comment: Yes, but `rds_superuser` is *not* a superuser in the PostgreSQL sense. You never get a superuser in a hosted database, since that would allow you to access the operating system.

Comment: Thank you, got it. I will use the respective owners of databases/tables to grant other roles privileges.